# Google cloud platform to S3/Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, amazon-redshift

Is there anyway programmatically in Python to ingest data from Google cloud platform in S3? My ultimate aim is to get data from Google Big Query to Redshift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use gsutil to copy data from a Google Cloud Storage bucket to an Amazon s3 bucket, using a command like this

```
gsutil -m rsync -rd gs://gcs-bucket s3://s3-bucket
```

no need for python code.

Comment: Thanks, this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have a look at https://rclone.org/ it supports copying data across many cloud storages including Google Storage and AWS S3.